# Merging a formatted and unformatted dataset

Tags: sas

I'm trying to merge the following two tables, but as one is 'formatted' the identifiers in both tables don't match up. How can I merge based on the formatted values or alternatively, when the PROC TABULATE data is output to a dataset, get ONLY the aggregated raw data and not the raw data with a format applied to it?

```
proc sql; create table first(eventtime num,node char(100), stake num, misc num); quit;
proc sql;  insert into first (eventtime, node, stake, misc)                                                                                         
    values(1, '', 10, 59867984)
    values(2, 'L', 2,349587)
    values(2, 'W', 30,345345)
    values(3, 'LL',40,345345)
    values(3, "LW/WL",50,145345)
    values(3, 'WW',60,3245234)
    values(4, 'LLL',70,675)
    values(4, 'LLW/LWL/LWW',80,2342546)
    values(4, "WLL/WLW/WWL",90,2345)
    values(4, 'WWW',100,2342567)
    values(5, 'LLLL',110,34534534)
    values(5, "LLLW/LLWL/LLWW/LWLL",120,8767)
    values(5, "LWLW/LWWL/LWWW/WLLL/WLLW/WLWL",130,1342345)
    values(5, "WLWW/WWLL/WWLW/WWWL",140,467876)
    values(5, 'WWWW',150,1345);                                                                                                                                                                                                         
quit; 

proc sql; create table second(eventtime num,node char(29), stake num); quit;
proc sql;  insert into second (eventtime, node, stake)                                                                                         
    values(1, '',11)
    values(2, 'L',21)
    values(2, 'W',31)
    values(3, 'LL',41)
    values(3, "LW",51)
    values(3, "WL",51)
    values(3, 'WW',61)
    values(4, 'LLL',71)
    values(4, 'LLW',81)
    values(4, 'LWL',81)
    values(4, 'LWW',81)
    values(4, "WLL",91)
    values(4, "WLW",91)
    values(4, "WWL",91)
    values(4, 'WWW',101)
    values(5, 'LLLL',111)
    values(5, "LLLW",121)
    values(5, "LLWL",121)
    values(5, "LLWW",121)
    values(5, "LWLL",121)
    values(5, "LWLW",131)
    values(5, "LWWL",131)
    values(5, "LWWW",131)
    values(5, "WLLL",131)
    values(5, "WLLW",131)
    values(5, "WLWL",131)
    values(5, "WLWW",141)
    values(5, "WWLL",141)
    values(5, "WWLW",141)
    values(5, "WWWL",141)
    values(5, 'WWWW',151);                                                                                                                                                                                                         
quit; 

proc format lib=work; value $node_group  (NOTSORTED)
    'LW', 'WL'="LW/WL"
    'LLW', 'LWL', 'LWW'='LLW/LWL/LWW'
    'WLL', 'WLW', 'WWL'="WLL/WLW/WWL"
    'LLLW', 'LLWL', 'LLWW','LWLL'="LLLW/LLWL/LLWW/LWLL"
    'LWLW', 'LWWL','LWWW','WLLL','WLLW','WLWL'="LWLW/LWWL/LWWW/WLLL/WLLW/WLWL"
    'WLWW','WWLL','WWLW','WWWL'="WLWW/WWLL/WWLW/WWWL"
;quit;

proc tabulate data=second out=crosstaboutput missing; *classdata=foo ;
    title ' ';
    var stake;
    class eventTime node;
    table eventTime="B6et"*node="Node",stake="Sumstake"*SUM;
    *table eventTime="Bet"*node="Node",stake="Stake"*(N Median*f=10.2);
    format node $node_group.;
run;

*Only picks up those 'nodes' upon which no format has been applied;
data third;
  update first(in=H1) crosstaboutput(in=H2);
  by node;
  if H1 and H2;
run;
proc print;run;

/*This doesn't work at all */
proc sort data=first; by node; run;
proc sort data=crosstaboutput(drop=_: rename=()); by node; run;
data third;
  merge first crosstaboutput;
  by node;
run;
proc print;run;
```

Comment: Don't see why this needs to be a new questino, it's the same as the other one.  Keith's solution there works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data crosstaboutput_fmt;
    set crosstaboutput (rename=(node=node_orig));
    length node $29;
    node = put(node_orig, $node_group.);
run;
```

Renames original unformatted node into node_orig and creates new node variable containing formatted values of original node variable:

```
length node $29;
node = put(node_orig, $node_group.);
```